# passing data from an activity to BROADCAST receiver

Tags: android

i want to pass some data from a edittextpreference to my broadcastreciever that is recieving SMS.... how can i do that...the following code represents what i have been doing but that does not works....

```
public class AppPreferences extends PreferenceActivity{

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle b)
   {
      super.onCreate(b);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

       prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

      Log.v("",  prefs.getString("Spam", null));
      Bundle ba = new Bundle();
      ba.putString("spam",prefs.getString("Spam",null));
   }

}
```

while getting it as

```
                spam=bundle.getString("spam");
Log.v("Bundle", spam);
```

does not works...how can i perform that...

simple i want to get text from the edittextpreference that have been entered by the user and then i want to get the text in the BoradCast Receiver to match some certain words in the incoming messages....

Answer (score 0):

If the data bit is a preference, you must get it in the receiver from a `Preferences` object:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

//...

public void onReceive(Context Ctxt, Intent in)
{
    //...
    SharedPreferences Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Ctxt);
    spam = Prefs.getString("spam", "");
```

EDIT: nothing special about that class, except you should not construct it directly (as in `new SharedPreferences()`). You get instances of `SharedPreferences` from a `PreferenceManager`, as depicted above.

EDIT2: extras are stored in the Intent object as a name-value collection. When you create an intent to invoke a receiver, you store extras like this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Ctxt, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
in.putExtra("foo", "Hello world"); //that's a string extra
in.putExtra("bar", 17); //that's an integer extra
```

On the receiving end:

```
public void onReceive(Context Ctxt, Intent in)
{
    String Foo = in.getStringExtra("foo");
    int Bar = in.getStringExtra("bar");
    //and so forth
```

Comment: the thing is i cant even do the SharedPreference becuase it wont let me import the SharedPreference class and gives an error like create class SharedPreference...there isnt any option for importing the SharePreference class...

Comment: One More thing how do i pass extras of intent to the broadcast receiver

Comment: but i dont want to initiate the BroadCastReceiver class myslef because it will only b called when something is received...

Comment: If you want the system to call your receiver (as opposed to your own activity), you have no control over the contents of the Intent - the system builds the intent object, not you. You can pass data to the receiver in preferences though.

Comment: so it means that i cant pass data through the intents then...?

Comment: If your code creates the intent, then yes. If not, then no :)